# Save JSON response from MySQL in Local Storage

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json, html

I have a problem with my PhoneGap app. I need to get an ID selected by user from index.html to view.html. For example, user choose a link with name on index.html and then press on this link and the view.html page will display an information about "something". With Ajax I make a request to 1.php which returns me a JSON.

```
while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result_1)) {
$arr[] = $obj;}
echo '{"notes":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
```

The 1.php script return me the next JSON:

> {"notes":[{"ID":"1000043","text":"Test ","dt":"2015-02-04 20:46:22"},{"ID":"1000037","text":"Here we go AGAIN!!","dt":"2015-02-03 07:42:42"},{"ID":"1000035","text":"Teoriya veroyatnosti - 27 ballov? ","dt":"2015-02-02 19:07:33"},{"ID":"1000032","text":"Test again?!","dt":"2015-01-20 12:48:47"}]}

Now if user choose the link with ID-1000043, the app should to display all info about this ID. I try tu use $_SESSION method, but I save only the first ID. After it I try the local storage. My request is:

```
var url="someurl.com/1.php";
$.getJSON(url,function(json){
$.each(json.notes,function(i,info){
var id = [];
id = info.ID;
localStorage.setItem('test_id',JSON.stringify(id));
```

On the view.html I have a function which display an ID from local storage... But it also save only the first ID, or an array of IDs'.  But my purpose is to get a selected ID and then display an info for user.

Update #1.
At first attempt I user getItem. It only displays the first ID from MySQL. I use:

```
 var store_id = JSON.parse(localStorage["id"]);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: 1) How to save JSON response from MySQL in local storage (ID)?
2) How to get selected the ID by selected link from local storage?

Comment: `.setItem()` is not working for you? You should also be able to use `getItem()`.